# How to call a function, defined in c# from boo?

Tags: c#, boo

I'm using `Boo` as the script engine in my C# program where I need to run user-defined scripts. How can I call a function which is defined in my C# code, from inside the `Boo` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import assembly with the class defining necessary method. Than create instance of the class and call method or just call it if it's static. Another way it's add call to the function to implicit base class if you are using Rhino DSL. Anyway, it would be good to know more details.